# В чем может быть причина не корректной работы модуля random.shuffle в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решал задачу на Python, но при использовании модуля random.shuffle периодически, в консоль, выводит не корректный ответ. Без использования модуля ошибки не возникает!

Даны действительные числа a1, a2, ..., аn. Среди них есть положительные и отрицательные. Заменить нулями те числа, величина которых по модулю больше максимального числа (|ai| > max{a1, a2, ..., аn}).

```
import random
c = [2, -2, -6, -8, 7, -9, 1, -3, -5, -11, 3, -7, -10, 0, -1, 4, -4, -12, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(c)
b = max(c)
for i in c:
    if abs(c[i]) > b:
        c[i] = 0
print(c)
```

Так вот, может вывести такой ответ:

```
[0, -7, -2, 0, 0, -5, -3, 5, -6, -4, <strong>-11</strong>, 0, 3, -1, 4, 7, 1, 0, 2, 6].
```

Где `<strong>-11</strong>` не должно быть!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модуль `shuffle` тут ни при чем. Вы не правильно пользуетесь циклом `for`. `i` - это не счетчик цикла, а именно элемент из `c`. Вам нужно отдельно завести счетчик и обращаться через него к элементу, который хотите обнулить:

```
import random
c = [2, -2, -6, -8, 7, -9, 1, -3, -5, -11, 3, -7, -10, 0, -1, 4, -4, -12, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(c)
b = max(c)
i = 0
for el in c:
    if abs(el) > b:
        c[i] = 0
    i += 1

print(c)
```

А вообще задачу можно решить гораздо короче, без цикла, а с помощью встроенной функции `map`:

```
import random
c = [2, -2, -6, -8, 7, -9, 1, -3, -5, -11, 3, -7, -10, 0, -1, 4, -4, -12, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(c)
b = max(c)
d = map(lambda x: 0 if abs(x) > b else x, c)
print(list(d))
```

Comment: Для  счетчика обычно используют `enumerate`, а не заводят отдельную переменную которую постоянно увеличивают на 1.

Comment: Блин, точно! Тупанул! Спасибо, допетрил.

Comment: @Arnial, это было бы все-равно не правильно, я же специально привел более идиоматичное решение.